# How does Ubuntu detect a smartphone without any drivers?

Tags: usb, android, samsung, upnp

The smartphone in this context is a Samsung Galaxy S i9000.

Before when I've tried to transfer files to and from a computer running windows I've always needed drivers for the smartphone to be detected.

However with Ubuntu, I simply plugged the phone in and it was recognised instantly.

Does this happen the way it does because Ubuntu comes with preloaded drivers and windows does not? Or is it because android is part of the Linux family and therefore communication between the two Linux devices is much easier to set up?

How does Ubuntu do this?

Comment: The drivers are built into the kernel, MTP protocol - http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/MTP

Comment: Have a look at the log files and you might get some more information. Open a terminal and write 'sudo tail -f /var/log/{dmesg.log,messages,syslog}' (adjust filenames if I remember wrong) and then look at what is printed. You might notice udev there. Command 'man udev' might help you to get more details.